# Wrong section counter for references when using titlesec

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, numbering, titlesec

Changing the style of my sections using the package `titlesec` works fine with these lines

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering{\Roman{section}.}}{}{1em}{}
```

but after adding my literature to the end of the file...

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{literature}
```

...the counter doesn't increase and the spacing is not entirely correct for the references section. However, the heading has the defined section style. Do you have a solution for having a consistent counter?

Comment: Hi lukas [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's hard to tell what's causing your problem at the moment- could you make your snippets into a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem? It will help both you and anyone that might be able to help. Welcome :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not convenient to include the counter in the second argument of `\titleformat`; this will cause starred sections to be numbered in an "unorthodox" way, as the following simple example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering{\Roman{section}.}}{}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\section*{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following wrong result (the numbering is wrong, the spacing between the number and the title is wrong and the counter for subordinate sectional units isn't reset appropriately):

[image]

The right way to proceed here is to redefine `\thesection` previously to use Roman numerals, as the following example illustrates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author= "The Author",
  journal = "The Journal",
  pages= "1-2",
  year="2012"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\large\scshape\filcenter}{\thesection.}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\cite{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to number the bibliography section, you can use the `etoolbox` package to patch the `\thebibliography` command to use `\section` instead of the default `\section*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\section}{}{}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author= "The Author",
  journal = "The Journal",
  pages= "1-2",
  year="2012"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\large\scshape\filcenter}{\thesection.}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\cite{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not related to the original problem but `\centering` doesn't have arguments, so instead of `\centering{text}` one should use something like `{\centering text\par}`
(the braces are only required if it is necessary to explicitly group to keep the effect local).